# RLMObject property NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I understand that RLMObjects cannot store NSDecimalNumber.  To get around this, I tried the following, but failed:

```
    private dynamic var _amount:    String = ""
    public var amount: NSDecimalNumber {
    get { return NSDecimalNumber(string: _amount) }
    set { _amount = newValue.stringValue }
}
```

I am getting a failure stating the RLMObjects cannot store NSDecimalNumbers.  I was under the impression that non-dynamic properties would not be stored in Realm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any property of `RLMObjects` must be `dynamic`. So `amount: NSDecimalNumber` property should be defined as `dynamic`

Like below:

```
private dynamic var _amount: String = ""

public dynamic var amount: NSDecimalNumber {
    get { return NSDecimalNumber(string: _amount) }
    set { _amount = newValue.stringValue }
}
```

And computed property should not be persisted. (Of course, `amount` property is `NSDecimalNumber`, so it can not be persisted in Realm. If `amount` property will be persisted, exception occured)

To prevent it, you can override `ignoredProperties()` method and return `"amount"` as string array.

```
override public class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject]! {
    return ["amount"]
}
```

Based on the above, complete class definition is as follows:

```
public class Product: RLMObject {
    private dynamic var _amount: String = ""

    public dynamic var amount: NSDecimalNumber {
        get { return NSDecimalNumber(string: _amount) }
        set { _amount = newValue.stringValue }
    }

    public override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String]! {
        return ["amount"]
    }
}
```